# Returning Metadata Fields with GraphQL?

Tags: entries, tags, query, graphql, api

I'm trying to pull as much information from the CMS as possible via the GraphQL API. I can't seem to find any info about how to extract the metadata information for the various entries in the CMS.

At the moment I can easily get things like title, url, etc, but no information on tags/categories/etc.

Anyone able to help?

Thanks!

Ailish

Answer (score 1):

Eeek I figured it out. I was expecting the GraphiQL editor to give me all queryable fields in the 'explore' interface. But looks like just typing the fields I wanted as part of the query manually works!